# Particular solution of $y'' +9y' +20y = e^{-4t}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have used the try method of $y = ae^{-4t}$ but I would end up with $16a - 36a + 20a = 1$ which is invalid. How else do I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $y=e^{-4t}$ is a solution for the homogeneous equation
$$y''+9y'+20y=0,$$
you should try $y=ate^{-4t}$ instead.